# Use trained discriminator in GAN to calculate probabilities

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning, dcgan

I followed this tutorial on GAN - https://github.com/adeshpande3/Generative-Adversarial-Networks/blob/master/Generative%20Adversarial%20Networks%20Tutorial.ipynb

I want to use the trained discriminator for calculating probabilities of test images(I trained on images which represent a certain set, and want to check the probability the test image resembles that set.) I used the following code - (after reloading the model)

```
newP= sess.run(Dx, feed_dict={x_placeholder: dataset2})
print("prob: " + str(newP)
```

But It is not giving probabilities, some random floats >1.  How to use the trained discrimanator for finding probabilities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use, `prob = tf.nn.sigmoid(Dx)` for your probabilities. Since `Dx` outputs a single value between 0-1, `softmax` for a single output will always be 1.(`exp(Dx)/exp(Dx) = 1`)

Comment: When we increase the no. of iterations, probabilities approach one.Can you say why? Perhaps its outputting the prob of image being real or fake(Since I am testing a real image, its giving close to 1). Any idea how can I get probability for my case.